# I have two tables Questions and answers, I would like to display all questions with details of their answers. Eg. 23(views) 12 (answers)

Tags: php, mysql

This doesn't show questions without answers

```
SELECT 
  M.id, M.j_surname, 
  Q.id as qid, Q.qus_view_count, Q.qus_owner, Q.qus_title, Q.qus_description,
  Q.qus_createddate, 
  COUNT(A.qus_id) as ans_count, 
  A.qus_id FROM jt_questions Q 
LEFT JOIN jt_members M ON M.id = Q.qus_owner 
LEFT JOIN jt_answers A ON Q.id = A.qus_id 
GROUP BY A.qus_id 
ORDER BY Q.qus_createddate DESC 
LIMIT $offset, $recordsPerPage;
```

Comment: No one actually cares about the PHP. Extract the query and show that, explaining why it doesn't do what you need.

Comment: are you developing a stackoverflow competitor over there? huh? huh?

Comment: Stackoverflow is King. Just a community project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY Q.id` not `GROUP BY A.qus_id`

For unanswered questions `A.qus_id` will all have a value of `NULL`

Comment: Already did that but it was not showing un answered questions.

Comment: Did you have a `WHERE` clause that you haven't shown us? This might have converted your `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Oh and now the query in the question has completely changed making my answer appear to be senseless. Great!

Comment: I removed the WHERE clause for simplicity.

Comment: @Frank - You could modify your existing query and add `WHERE A.qus_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

$offset = "1; drop table jt_answers; --";

EDIT

if what you did in your code looked like this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT 
  M.id, M.j_surname, 
  Q.id as qid, Q.qus_view_count, Q.qus_owner, Q.qus_title, Q.qus_description,
  Q.qus_createddate, 
  COUNT(A.qus_id) as ans_count, 
  A.qus_id FROM jt_questions Q 
LEFT JOIN jt_members M ON M.id = Q.qus_owner 
LEFT JOIN jt_answers A ON Q.id = A.qus_id 
GROUP BY A.qus_id 
ORDER BY Q.qus_createddate DESC 
LIMIT $offset, $recordsPerPage;";
```

All I would need to do is to get $offset to look like my original answer above. That would drop your jt_answers table.

You could validate these values, such as making sure $offset is a positive integer.

But really you should use MySQLi's parameter binding instead. That would replace the variables with ? and let you pass the variables into it so the database can decide how to handle them.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I would like to know where the security risk is in the code.I really appreciate your concern.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can I see an example? using bind method?

Comment: There are plenty examples all over php.net, just float around the mysqli docs. They are on the left nav of the link I put above.